# ASP Form inserts nothing instead of values

Tags: sql, asp.net, oledb

I'm using Visual Studio Express 2012 to try and make a form which updates an Access DB.

I'm using the following script at the top:

```
<script runat="server">
    private void NewCreate (object source, EventArgs e) {
      All.Insert();
    }
</script>
```

The data source and parameters:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="All" runat="server"
  ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Database %>"
  ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Database.ProviderName %>"
  SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [All]"
  InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [All] (UserRef,MgrRef,SiteRef,Date) VALUES (@User,@Mgr,@Site,@Date)">
  <insertparameters>
    <asp:formparameter name="Site" formfield="SiteDropDown" />
    <asp:formparameter name="Mgr"  formfield="MgrDropDown" />
    <asp:formparameter name="User"  formfield="UserDropDown" />
    <asp:formparameter name="Date"  formfield="DatePicker" />
  </insertparameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

One of the fields:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="UserDropDown" runat="server"
  DataSourceID="UserList"
  DataTextField="UserName"
  DataValueField="UserRef">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

And it's data source:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="UserList" runat="server"
  ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Database %>"
  ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Database.ProviderName %>"
  SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Users] WHERE [Users].UserTypeRef=1">
```

There are another 4 fields, however when I submit it inserts null data.

If I turn set required to "Yes" in Access (like I did originally) I get an error saying "You must enter a value in the [All].UserRef field

Can anyone see why it's not taking the data from the dropdown boxes? Thanks

Comment: Are you using a master page?

Comment: Yes. I'm new to this, just created a default Web Form; Master is "~/Site.Master"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using a Master Page, the controls on your form will have a prefix before their names. When they post back to the server, instead of `SiteDropDown`, the name will look something like `ctl00$ContentPlaceholder1$SiteDropDown`. When the `FormParameter` looks for an entry in the posted data called `SiteDropDown`, it won't find one.

The simplest solution is to replace your [`<asp:FormParameter />` tags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.formparameter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with [`<asp:ControlParameter />` tags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.controlparameter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="All" runat="server"
  ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Database %>"
  ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Database.ProviderName %>"
  SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [All]"
  InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [All] (UserRef,MgrRef,SiteRef,Date) VALUES (@User,@Mgr,@Site,@Date)">
  <insertparameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter 
      Name="Site" 
      ControlID="SiteDropDown" 
      PropertyName="SelectedValue"
    />
    <asp:ControlParameter 
      Name="Mgr"
      ControlID="MgrDropDown" 
      PropertyName="SelectedValue"
    />
    <asp:ControlParameter 
      Name="User"
      ControlID="UserDropDown" 
      PropertyName="SelectedValue"
    />
    <asp:ControlParameter 
      Name="Date"
      ControlID="DatePicker"
    />
  </insertparameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```